# Angular hide buttons depending on url

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to hide/show buttons depending on URL. The code works but I am  not sure if I am using the correct way.

```
MyApp.run( function($rootScope, $location) {
$rootScope.$watch(function() { 
   return $location.$$absUrl;
},
function (a) {

    if (a === "http://localhost/Home/Index")
    {
        $rootScope.btn1 = true;
        $rootScope.btn2 = true;
        $rootScope.btn3 = true;
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Are those buttons are dependent on pages you display or dey are always in one specific page ? Because just to hide buttons depending on url you shouldn't opt for $rootScope

Comment: Have you tried to use $route service? There an event $routeChangeSuccess for that

Comment: you are trying to write your own controller routing logic, which is not necessary.  Create a route and a partial which contains these buttons.  Assuming you don't use this button in other partials, you will get what you need above.

Comment: Thank you these buttons are in the _Layout. I don't know how to create route and a partial. Could you please point me to the right direction, tutorial....

Comment: These buttons are for navigation to different pages and I would like to hide the button for a particular page if I am in this page.

Comment: It is not encouraged to have watches on rootscope, and changing it frequently, Did you try somenavigation bar like https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar? 
Or i would suggest to add style for buttons(display:none).

Comment: Thank you. I am using Angular material not bootstrap in my application